# How to properly use mainEntityOfPage for a blog details page?

Tags: blogs, schema.org, json-ld

I've read several answers as to what `mainEntityOfPage` is and how to use it, and each one was more confusing than the last.

So my question is specific; I have a website which contains a blog section. On the blog details page I want to use structured data in JSON-LD format.

My question: would my `mainEntityOfPage` be `WebPage` or `BlogPosting`?

Should I use this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "BlogPosting",
    }
}
</script>
```

or this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BlogPosting",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm thinking the `mainEntityOfPage` is `BlogPosting`, so first example, yes? Or do I still have it all wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of [`mainEntityOfPage`](https://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) is:

> Indicates a page (or other CreativeWork) for which this thing is the main entity being described.

The main entity on a blog post page is the blog post, not the page. So, the second snippet is correct:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage"
  }
}
```

If you want to use the first snippet (so that `WebPage` is the top-level item), you have to use [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) instead of `mainEntityOfPage`:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "BlogPosting"
  }
}
```

Note 1: `mainEntity` and `mainEntityOfPage` are inverse properties, so these two snippets mean the same.

Note 2: Maybe it helps to read it as "is the `mainEntityOfPage`", and "has `mainEntity`".

Note 3: You can use [`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage) (instead of `WebPage`) on the blog post pages.